# How to call custom block file in custom theme in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-theme

How to call custom block file in custom theme in magento 2

> app/code/Cm/Mod/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>   
      <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Cm\Mod\Block\Display"
               name="product.view.extra"
               template="Cm_Mod::product/view/extra.phtml"
              after="product.info.overview">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Cm/Mod/view/frontend/templates/product/view/extra.phtml

```
<p>custom block</p>
```

How to call a `extra.phtml` file in **custom theme** in `magento 2` 
someone please help me

Comment: is the path to your file is app/code/Cm/Mod/view/forntend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml ?

Comment: s layout file is placed in above mentioned path

Comment: it should be frontend not forntend

Comment: sry its a typo mistake i was corrected it in the above question

Comment: can you please tell me how to call a  custom block in custom theme

Comment: @divyasekar you have created block file correctly location?

Comment: @divyasekar You did right way and code looks good, i seen white space on top of xml, please remove it if space is there.

Also please confirm small/capital character it might be a case.
Also check your block is  extends with class \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

Comment: @divyasekar please keep in mind clear cache every time when you update xml.